# WPF wrap header text on TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I have made a TreeView in WPF with 145px fixed width and all its child elements (TreeViewItems) has a header text that is wider than 145px, which means a horizontal scrollbar appears at the bottom of the TreeView.

I have managed to get rid of that scrollbar by adding:

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
```

To my TreeView.

However, the header text that is too wide is now being hidden, so I want to wrap the header text so it fits into the TreeView with 145px width.

I have searched for solutions on this and tried some of those I found, but still haven't got it working and it's making me frustrated!

Here is my XAML code:

```
<TreeView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Width="145" Name="tree_menu" >
   <TreeViewItem Header="This is a very long root element node text">
      <TreeViewItem Header="this is a very long child element node text" />
   </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

```
<TreeView Name="tree_menu">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Width="145"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Text="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeViewItem Header="This is a very long root element node text">
        <TreeViewItem Header="this is a very long child element node text" />
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```